# Python weather archive parser rp5.ru

Tags: python, parsing, request

Good day to all!

I need to download weather archives from the site https://rp5.ru/Weather archive_in_ostrove_heys (I will need to download them for all weather stations in the future, in a cycle).

On the site, the process goes like this:
You enter the station and the dates and click on the "Select file in GZ" button, after that the file is generated and the download button appears, by clicking on which a redirect to the file takes place and it is downloaded.

I am trying to reproduce the request that is sent to the server when clicking on "Select file in GZ", however, an error is received in the response from the server (that is, the request passes, but is not successful). Please tell me what the error may be and how it can be fixed?

I reviewed all the questions and answers on parsing from this site, but apparently something has changed on the site and no ready-made solutions from the forums do not work.

I think it may be related to cookies, but I tried to get them first with a get request and send them in a post request, but nothing comes out either.

```
myUrl = "https://rp5.ru/responses/reFileSynop.php"
myHeader = {}
myHeader["Accept"] = "text/html, */*; q=0.01"
myHeader["Accept-Encoding"] = "gzip, deflate, br"
myHeader["Accept-Language"] = "ru-RU,ru;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4"
myHeader["Connection"] = "keep-alive"
myHeader["Content-Length"] = "110"
myHeader["Content-Type"] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
myHeader["Host"] = "rp5.ru"
myHeader["Origin"] = "https://rp5.ru"
myHeader["Referer"] = "https://rp5.ru/"
myHeader["sec-ch-ua-mobile"] = "?0"
myHeader["Sec-Fetch-Dest"] = "empty"
myHeader["Sec-Fetch-Mode"] = "cors"
myHeader["Sec-Fetch-Site"] = "same-origin"
myHeader["sec-ch-ua"] = '" Not A;Brand";v="99", "Chromium";v="90", "Yandex";v="90"'
myHeader["User-Agent"] = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36"
myHeader["X-Requested-With"] = "XMLHttpRequest"
myData = {'wmo_id':'27612','a_date1':'21.06.2021','a_date2':'20.06.2021','f_ed3':'6','f_ed4':'6','f_ed5':'22','f_pe':'1','f_pe1':'1','lng_id':'2','type':'xls'} 
response = requests.post(myUrl, data=myData, headers=myHeader)
print(response.text)
```

Answer: Error #FS000;

Answer (score -1):

I think there is a problem with Windows, it does not redirect correctly. I tried to download using MAC OS and it downloaded for me.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30540767)